# Time machine - 10.12.5 no backup in x days” from TimeMachine notification

Tags: time-machine, notifications

Previously you would get a notification that says "no backup in x days".. but in 10.12.5 there is no notification.. is that feature no longer there where it doesn't tell you that you haven't backed up for awhile?

if not how do i get it back?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's still there. I saw it recently. It may be broken however, because it was reporting not having backed up for over 20 days, when in reality my oldest backup was only a few days old. It may not be working when it should be.

Comment: thats odd since my last backup was april 29... and no notifications

Comment: Me too, I have just discovered time machine hasn't backed up for a month, with no messages.